# React update API call having routing

Tags: javascript, reactjs, variables, components

I'm learning react. My first web app is a simple page, which requests API Covid-19 data about the USA and displays it into categories. I have used react router in order to display the same card component with different data passed using the `dataFinal` variable, which holds the API retrieved json. If I were to access one of the categories, which is not home, e.g., `/positiveIncrease`, I get an error:

```
Error in /~/index.js (46:255)
Cannot read property 'positiveIncrease' of undefined
```

I infer from the error that the render happens before the API gets data back from the json is retrieved and stored in an object. In order to solve the issue I tried conditional rendering with JSX inside the content part of the Card component `dataFinal.hospitalizedCurrently ? dataFinal.hospitalizedCurrently : "Loading..."`

This however doesn't seem to work. I also tried creating a boolean variable that holds whether the API call has finished but it also didn't work.

**The link to the app on Stackblitz is:**

Editor: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-covid-19-us-tracker?file=index.js

View: https://react-covid-19-us-tracker.stackblitz.io

Default file to show: index.js

- In order to replicate the issue just navigate through the menu to a
  random category different from Home and reload the page.

**API.js**

```
import React from 'react';
let loaded=false;
let dataFinal;
 fetch("https://api.covidtracking.com/v1/us/current.json")
 .then(data=>data.json())
 .then(data=>{
     dataFinal=data[0]
  })



export {dataFinal}
```

**Card.js**

```
import React from "react";
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import Card from "@material-ui/core/Card";
import CardActions from "@material-ui/core/CardActions";
import CardContent from "@material-ui/core/CardContent";
import Button from "@material-ui/core/Button";
import Typography from "@material-ui/core/Typography";
import { title, content } from "./Routing.js";

export default function Card(props) {
  return (
    <Card className="card">
      <CardContent>
        <Typography color="textSecondary" gutterBottom>
          {props.title}
        </Typography>
        <Typography variant="h5" component="h2">
          {props.content}
        </Typography>
      </CardContent>
      <CardActions>
        <Button
          onClick={() => {
            window.location = "https://www.cdc.gov/covid-data-tracker/#cases";
          }}
          size="small"
        >
          Learn More
        </Button>
        <br />
      </CardActions>
     { typeof props.content === "string" || props.content instanceof String ? "" : <CardContent>
        <p style={{ color: "red" }}>{repeat(props.content)}</p>
      </CardContent>}
    </Card>
  );
}
export { Content, Title };

const repeat = num => {
  if (typeof num === "string" || num instanceof String) {
    return "";
  }
  if (num < 2000) {
    return "♥ ".repeat(num);
  } else {
    return "♥ ".repeat(2000) + " and " + (num - 2000) + " more";
  }
};
```

**index.html**

```
<title>Covid-19 USA Visualization</title>
<div id="root"></div>
```

**index.js**

```
import React, { Component} from 'react';
import {render} from 'react-dom';
import './style.css';
import {dataFinal, loaded} from "./API.js"
import Routing from "./Routing.js"
import Card from "./Card.js"
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';
class App extends Component {
    render() {
      return(
        <div> <Routing/>
        <main>
            <Switch>
             <Route exact path="/" render={()=> <Card title={''} content={"Navigate through the menus on the top left"} />}> 
                </Route>
                <Route exact path="/positive" render={()=><Card title={'Positive'} content={dataFinal.positive ? dataFinal.positive : "Loading..."} />}> 
                </Route>
                 <Route exact path="/positiveIncrease" render={()=> <Card title={'Positive increase'} content={dataFinal.positiveIncrease ? dataFinal.positiveIncrease : "Loading..."} />}> 
                </Route>
                <Route exact path="/hospitalized" render={()=> <Card title={'Hospitalized'} content={dataFinal.hospitalized ? dataFinal.hospitalized : "Loading..."}/>}> 
                </Route>
                 <Route exact path="/hospitalizedCurrently" render={()=> <Card title={'Hospitalized currently'} content={dataFinal.hospitalizedCurrently ? dataFinal.hospitalizedCurrently : "Loading..." }/>}> 
                </Route>
                  <Route exact path="/dead" render={()=> <Card title={'Total dead'} content={dataFinal.death ? dataFinal.death : "Loading..." }/>}> 
                </Route>
                 <Route exact path="/icu" render={()=> <Card title={'Currently in intensive care unit'} content={dataFinal.inIcuCurrently ? dataFinal.inIcuCurrently : "Loading..." }/>}> 
                                 </Route>
                 <Route exact path="/culminativeicu" render={()=> <Card title={'Culminative in intensive care unit'} content={dataFinal.inIcuCumulative ? dataFinal.inIcuCumulative : "Loading..." }/>}> 
                </Route>
                 <Route exact path="/onventillatorsculminative" render={()=> <Card title={'Culminative on ventillators'} content={dataFinal.onVentilatorCumulative ? dataFinal.onVentilatorCumulative : "Loading..." }/>}> 
                </Route>
                 <Route exact path="/onventillatorscurrently" render={()=> <Card title={'Currently on ventillators'} content={dataFinal.onVentilatorCurrently ? dataFinal.onVentilatorCurrently : "Loading..." }/>}> 
                </Route>
                 <Route exact path="/recovered" render={()=> <Card title={'Recovered'} content={dataFinal.recovered ? dataFinal.recovered : "Loading..." }/>}> 
                </Route>
                 <Route exact path="/deadIncrease" render={()=> <Card title={'Dead Increase'} content={dataFinal.deathIncrease ? dataFinal.deathIncrease : "Loading..." }/>}> 
                 </Route>
                  <Route exact path="/hospitalizedIncrease" render={()=> <Card title={'Hospitalized increase'} content={dataFinal.deathIncrease ? dataFinal.deathIncrease : "Loading..." }/>}> 
                 </Route>
            </Switch>
        </main>
        </div>
        )  
    }
}


render( <BrowserRouter>
        <App /> 
    </BrowserRouter>, document.getElementById('root'));
```

**Routing.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import clsx from 'clsx';
import { makeStyles, useTheme } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import Drawer from '@material-ui/core/Drawer';
import CssBaseline from '@material-ui/core/CssBaseline';
import AppBar from '@material-ui/core/AppBar';
import Toolbar from '@material-ui/core/Toolbar';
import List from '@material-ui/core/List';
import Typography from '@material-ui/core/Typography';
import Divider from '@material-ui/core/Divider';
import IconButton from '@material-ui/core/IconButton';
import MenuIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Menu';
import ChevronLeftIcon from '@material-ui/icons/ChevronLeft';
import ChevronRightIcon from '@material-ui/icons/ChevronRight';
import ListItem from '@material-ui/core/ListItem';
import ListItemIcon from '@material-ui/core/ListItemIcon';
import ListItemText from '@material-ui/core/ListItemText';
import {Content,Title} from "./Card.js"
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Switch,Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import ReplayIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Replay';
import Box from '@material-ui/core/Box';
import {retrieve} from "./API"
import 'fontsource-roboto';
const drawerWidth = 200;

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  root: {
    display: 'flex',
  },
  appBar: {
    transition: theme.transitions.create(['margin', 'width'], {
      easing: theme.transitions.easing.sharp,
      duration: theme.transitions.duration.leavingScreen,
    }),
  },
  appBarShift: {
    width: `calc(100% - ${drawerWidth}px)`,
    marginLeft: drawerWidth,
    transition: theme.transitions.create(['margin', 'width'], {
      easing: theme.transitions.easing.easeOut,
      duration: theme.transitions.duration.enteringScreen,
    }),
  },
  menuButton: {
    marginRight: theme.spacing(2),
  },
  hide: {
    display: 'none',
  },
  drawer: {
    width: drawerWidth,
    flexShrink: 0,
  },
  drawerPaper: {
    width: drawerWidth,
  },
  drawerHeader: {
    display: 'flex',
    alignItems: 'center',
    padding: theme.spacing(0, 1),
    // necessary for content to be below app bar
    ...theme.mixins.toolbar,
    justifyContent: 'flex-end',
  },
  content: {
    flexGrow: 1,
    padding: theme.spacing(3),
    transition: theme.transitions.create('margin', {
      easing: theme.transitions.easing.sharp,
      duration: theme.transitions.duration.leavingScreen,
    }),
    marginLeft: -drawerWidth,
  },
  contentShift: {
    transition: theme.transitions.create('margin', {
      easing: theme.transitions.easing.easeOut,
      duration: theme.transitions.duration.enteringScreen,
    }),
    marginLeft: 0,
  },
}));

export default function PersistentDrawerLeft() {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const theme = useTheme();
  const [open, setOpen] = React.useState(false);

  const handleDrawerOpen = () => {
    setOpen(true);
  };

  const handleDrawerClose = () => {
    setOpen(false);
  };

  return (
    <div className={classes.root}>
      <CssBaseline />
      <AppBar
        position="fixed"
        className={clsx(classes.appBar, {
          [classes.appBarShift]: open,
        })}
      >
        <Toolbar>
          <IconButton
            color="inherit"
            aria-label="Open drawer"
            onClick={handleDrawerOpen}
            edge="start"
            className={clsx(classes.menuButton, open && classes.hide)}
          >
            <MenuIcon />
          </IconButton>
          <Typography variant="h6" noWrap>
USA Covid-19 Visualization          
</Typography>
        </Toolbar>
      </AppBar>
      <Drawer
        className={classes.drawer}
        anchor="bottom"
        open={open}
        classes={{
          paper: classes.drawerPaper,
        }}
      >
        <div className={classes.drawerHeader}>
          <IconButton onClick={handleDrawerClose}>
            {theme.direction === 'ltr' ? <ChevronLeftIcon /> : <ChevronRightIcon />}
          </IconButton>
        </div>
        <Divider />
        <List>
        <Link onClick={()=>setOpen(false)} style={{textDecoration:"none",color:"black"}} to="/">  <ListItem  button key={"Home"}>
              <ListItemText  primary={"Home"} />
            </ListItem> </Link>
            <Divider />
          <Link onClick={()=>setOpen(false)}  style={{textDecoration:"none",color:"black"}} to="/positive">  <ListItem  button key={"Positive"}>
              <ListItemText  primary={"Positive"} />
            </ListItem> </Link>
             <Link onClick={()=>setOpen(false)} style={{textDecoration:"none",color:"black"}} to="/positiveIncrease">  <ListItem  button key={"PositiveIncrease"}>
              <ListItemText  primary={"Positive increase"} />
            </ListItem> </Link>
            <Divider />
         <Link onClick={()=>setOpen(false)}  style={{textDecoration:"none",color:"black"}}  to="/hospitalized">   <ListItem  button key={"Hospitalized"}>
              <ListItemText primary={"Hospitalized culminative"} />
            </ListItem></Link>
            <Link onClick={()=>setOpen(false)}  style={{textDecoration:"none",color:"black"}}  to="/hospitalizedCurrently">  <ListItem  button key={"hospitalizedCurrently"}>
              <ListItemText primary={"Hospitalized currently"} />
            </ListItem></Link>
             <Link onClick={()=>setOpen(false)}  style={{textDecoration:"none",color:"black"}}  to="/hospitalizedIncrease">  <ListItem  button key={"hospitalizedIncrease"}>
              <ListItemText primary={"Hospitalized increase"} />
            </ListItem></Link>
                        <Divider />

           <Link onClick={()=>setOpen(false)}  style={{textDecoration:"none",color:"black"}}  to="/dead">  <ListItem  button key={"Dead"}>
              <ListItemText primary={"Dead Culminative"} />
            </ListItem></Link>
             <Link onClick={()=>setOpen(false)}  style={{textDecoration:"none",color:"black"}}  to="/deadIncrease">  <ListItem  button key={"DeadIncrease"}>
              <ListItemText primary={"Dead increase"} />
            </ListItem></Link>
                        <Divider />
             <Link onClick={()=>setOpen(false)}  style={{textDecoration:"none",color:"black"}}  to="/icu">  <ListItem  button key={"Icu"}>
              <ListItemText primary={"Currently in ICU"} />
            </ListItem></Link>
             <Link onClick={()=>setOpen(false)}  style={{textDecoration:"none",color:"black"}}  to="/culminativeicu">  <ListItem  button key={"culminativeIcu"}>
              <ListItemText primary={"In ICU culminative"} />
            </ListItem></Link>
                        <Divider />
             <Link onClick={()=>setOpen(false)}  style={{textDecoration:"none",color:"black"}}  to="/onventillatorsculminative">  <ListItem  button key={"onventillatorsculminative"}>
              <ListItemText primary={"On ventillators culminative"} />
            </ListItem></Link>
             <Link onClick={()=>setOpen(false)}  style={{textDecoration:"none",color:"black"}}  to="/onventillatorscurrently">  <ListItem  button key={"onventillatorscurrently"}>
              <ListItemText primary={"On ventillators currently"} />
            </ListItem></Link>
                        <Divider />
             <Link onClick={()=>setOpen(false)}  style={{textDecoration:"none",color:"black"}}  to="/recovered">  <ListItem  button key={"recovered"}>
              <ListItemText primary={"Recovered"} />
            </ListItem></Link>
            <Divider />
            <center><Typography  style={{color:"grey",fontSize:"1vmax",marginTop:"1.5vmax",marginBottom:"1vmax"}} >Created by Atanas Bobev</Typography></center>
        </List>
      </Drawer>
      <main
        className={clsx(classes.content, {
          [classes.contentShift]: open,
        })}
      >
   
      </main>
    </div>
  );
  
}
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "react",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "1.2.30",
    "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome": "0.1.11",
    "@material-ui/core": "4.11.0",
    "@material-ui/icons": "4.9.1",
    "@types/react": "16.9.46",
    "clsx": "1.1.1",
    "font-awesome": "4.7.0",
    "fontsource-roboto": "^3.0.3",
    "material-ui": "0.20.2",
    "react": "16.13.1",
    "react-dom": "16.13.1",
    "react-router-dom": "5.2.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "react-scripts": "latest"
  }
}
```

**style.css**

```
h1, p {
  font-family: Lato;
}
.card{
  width:90vw;
  margin-left:5vw;
  margin-top:5vw;
}
Link{
  color:black;
  text-decoration:none;
}
```

How to fix this routing(API) issue? I would be happy I you could suggest some better practices I have missed in this app. Thank you in advance.

[Working section Card element with API data after click](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UXe3C.png)

[Non-working after reload](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NJwTq.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ciao, to avoid the error you could do:

```
<Route exact path="/positiveIncrease" render={()=> <Card title={'Positive increase'} content={dataFinal ? dataFinal.positiveIncrease ? dataFinal.positiveIncrease : "Loading..." : "Loading..."} />}> 
</Route>
```

The error appears because on reloading page you lost `dataFinal`. Apply this change to all the routes and problem should be solved.

[Here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-covid-19-us-tracker-mhn4si?file=index.js) your code modified.

**EDIT**

As you said in comment, this is a partial fix (because if you reload the page, "Loading..." stills there and data will be not reloaded).

In order to totally fix your problem, you have to change a little bit your solution:

1. `componentDidMount`: when you reload the page from "positive increase" route for example, your `dataFinal` will be lost and page cannot shows data you need. But we know that, every time page will be reloaded, react fires `componentDidMount` function. Ok, so we could use it:

   ```
   class App extends Component {
    ...
    componentDidMount(){
      // ok here we can do some to reload data we need
    }
   ```
2. `API.js`: your solution now returns just `dataFinal` from `API.js`. So far so good. But lets say I want to re-fetch data every time I want, with your solution is impossible. So lets modify a little bit `API.js` in this way:

   ```
   export default function(){
     return fetch("https://api.covidtracking.com/v1/us/current.json")
     .then(data=>data.json())
     .then(data=>{
        return data[0];
      })
   }
   ```

As you can see, now API.js export a function that returns values fetched (not only the values fetched as previous implementation).

3. `this.state.dataFinal`: Ok now we have all the elements we need. Lets go on `App.js` file and use them. First of all, put `dataFinal` into `App.js` state:

   ```
   class App extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.state = {
        dataFinal: {}
      }
    }
    ...
   ```

Then, use the function we import from `API.js` to update `App.js` state every time component will be reloaded:

```
componentDidMount(){
  fetchCovidData().then(data => {
    this.setState({dataFinal: data});
  })
}
```

And that's it! Now,every time user reloads page, independently in which route he is, `dataFinal` will be re-fetched and displayed correctly.

In this implementation, you could also avoid to write the condition I previously suggested (because I initialized `dataFinal` as a void object `{}`).

[Here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-covid-19-us-tracker-mhn4si?file=index.js) your code modified.

Comment: This partially fixed the issue. After the reload the Loading... screen appears without the data being updated after the API is loaded after a few seconds.

Comment: Ciao @Atanas, I updated my answer with a solution that could help to totally solve your problem. Hope you find it better than previous answer. Sorry for late response.

Comment: No problem. Have a nice day :)